# How to get the word under the cursor in a Windows Word editor or in a Pdf editor with using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pdf, get, ms-word

I'm trying to prepare a Delphi Project. In this project I need get the word which was selected by user in Windows Word editor or in Pdf editor. So far I saw some examples about getting the word under the cursor in Memo or in Notbook, but I need to get the word under the cursor in other editor like MsWord or AdobePdf editor.

Comment: I think those are two completely different questions so you ought to edit one out and post it as a separate q.  What you want can be done for Word using its OLE automation library, but so far as I know, the Adobe one for Acrobat doesn't provide direct access to the text, if any, in a Pdf - I think you need to use its internal Javascript for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using D7 and Word 2007:

```
procedure TForm1.GetSelectedText;
var
  MSWord,
  Selection,
  SelectedText : OleVariant;
begin
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;

  Selection := MSWord.Selection;
  if not VarIsEmpty(Selection) then begin
    SelectedText := Selection.Text;
    Caption := SelectedText;
  end;

end;
```

Obviously, it would be trivial to re-write the above as a stand-along function and pass in a reference to an existing MSWord object, if you already have one elsewhere in your code.

Like I said in my comment, doing the equivalent in Acrobat/Pdf is a different technical question, requiring its own q.  However, having investigated it, I don't think there's a straightforward method of doing it.

- If you import the Acrobat type library into Delphi, giving you a unit Acrobat_Tlb.Pas, you'll see that it contains a COM object interface, CAcroPDDoc.
- You can instantiate that object for the document currently active in Acrobat.  However, one* of the weird things about Acrobat's COM object model is that it doesn't provide any useful access to the text contents, if any, in the document.
- However, from the CAcroPDDoc interface, you can get access to Acrobat's internal JavaScript object for the document by using a call to CAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject.
- Once you've got a reference to the JS object, you can do a very limited amount of text processing, in particular there's a method GetPageNthWord(Page, WordNum, StripWhiteSpace) that "does what it says on the tin".  That's as far as I've got, implementation-wise (if you want to see the code, post a new question).
- From there, if you have the time, know-how and inclination - and I currently don't - you can apparently retrieve another JS object representing the on-screen selection rectangle and by somehow comparing that with the coordinates of the various Nth words from GetPageNthWord, you can identify which of them is/are selected.  Not QED, ISTM.

All of which is a sufficient performance that if it were me, I'd just tell the user to copy the selection to the clipboard, where it would be easy to pick up from Delphi code.

***** - Sometimes working with the Acrobat automation I get the feeling that Adobe have gone out of their way to not make it easy to get at the text in a .PDF file.  Whether that's anything to do with the possibly apocryphal story that originally PDF was conceived as a write-only medium, so that you could guarantee that you could put one in the field and be sure that it couldn't be modified, I don't know.

Comment: Dear Sir; For Pdf files I trying TacroPdf activex component to open pdf files but I can't get the text in pdf files to copy richedit component in Delphi 7. If you help me I'll be glad.

Comment: Well, if what I've written about MS Word worked for you, I'd be grateful if you could accept my answer.   Then, you should post a new q, worded similarly to this one, but only asking about Pdf, and I'll see if I can help you with that.

Comment: Dear sir; Thank you very much for your answer about word. I want to prepare a program, which will be get the meaning of the word from a dictionary when user select a word on an editor (word, pdf, ...). I have solved basicly by using richedit but you know richedit can't be used with pdf files.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do, but this site *requires* different technical problems - which is what getting text from MS Word and PDF are - to be raised as separate questions.  So please do the two things I suggested in my "Well, if what ..." comment above: a) accept my answer to this q and b) ask a separate one about PDF.  I will answer your *new* question about PDF as best I can: . I am not answering it in this one.